# Skipping duplicated when generating combinations

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
from collections import Counter
def groups(d, l, c = []):
   if l == len(c):
     yield c
   else:
      for i in d:
         if i not in c:
            _c = Counter([j for k in [*c, i] for j in k])
            if all(j < 3 for j in _c.values()):
               yield from groups(d, l, c+[i])

data = [(1,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,1),(3,2),(3,4)]
result = list(groups(data, 3))
```

This code is generating triples of pairs like this:
`[[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1)], [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)], [(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 1)],1[(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 4)], [(1, 2), (2, 5), (3, 1)], [(1, 2), (2, 5), (3, 4)] ...`

The problem is, that there are duplicates like this:

`[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1)] and [(2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 1)]`

Is there a way how to avoid them in process of generating?

Comment: Would you want to change the current code or just remove the duplicates from the result?

Comment: Change the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are reinventing the wheel. Simply use `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

data = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4)]
print(list(combinations(data, 3)))
# [((1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)), ((1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 5)), ...
```

You can confirm that this does not have repetitions by checking the length of the returned list (which is 56), which is exactly what you would expect (8 choose 3 is 56)

If you need to apply custom logic you can still do that:

```
from itertools import combinations

data = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4)]

wanted_combinations = []
for combination in combinations(data, 3):
    # apply logic
    if condition:
        wanted_combinations.append(combination)
```

Comment: I need special result as in example, not combinations.

Comment: @M.Barabas You can apply the logic on the returned generator from `combinations`. You will gain the correct result **and** better performance (`combinations` is implemented in C) as can be seen in my updated answer

Comment: I cannot go through all combinations, I am working with array of size 50 and generating 23-nties, I need to change code to generate only needed triples.

Comment: @M.Barabas In this case I think you will run into the same performance issues either way. 50 choose 23 is 108,043,253,365,600

Comment: Yes it is true, but when I will skip nties according the condition in process of generating, number of nties will be a lot smaller.

Comment: @M.Barabas But you still have to "generate" a combination in order to check if it satisfies a condition

Comment: No, code which I mentioned in question generate only combinations which I need, the only problem is, that there are duplicates.